# How do I get help for "echo" or other bash commands?

Tags: command-line, documentation

`man echo` works. but out of curiosity, does echo have something similar to a `--help` flag/parameter?

Comment: How about you simply try and see if it works?

Comment: I have tried it, Sir. and hence the question. Have edited it now to make it less confusing.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Assuming you are using bash, `echo` is a shell builtin (which you can see by running `type echo`). That means the man-page you want to read is `man bash`. Or you can get help on bash builtins and keywords with the `help` builtin, e.g. `help echo`.

The information you see when you run `man echo`, is for the external `echo` command, installed by GNU coreutils. (`type -a echo`).

To learn bash, read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide

Answer (score 9):

There are two `echo` The built-in command and another one, an executable placed in /bin/echo

The built-in (this is the default one) hasn't any help options far beyond the `help echo` built-in. Any flags placed and not listed there are presented as command result and there's no help command.

In the executable version instead `/bin/echo` there's a `--help` flag which prints usage. but you must call `/bin/echo` explicit.

Answer (score 5):

Other way would be using  **whatis** bash command for  example.

```
whatis echo             >>>> shows as following 

echo (1)             - display a line of text
```

According to [Whatis manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/whatis.1.html) , it displays manual page descriptions. Such as

```
 whatis whatis
whatis (1)           - display manual page descriptions
```

For Commands brief parameters or options try **`--usage`** infront of them as

```
whatis --usage
Usage: whatis [-dvrwl?V] [-C FILE] [-L LOCALE] [-m SYSTEM] [-M PATH] [-s LIST]
            [--debug] [--verbose] [--regex] [--wildcard] [--long]
            [--config-file=FILE] [--locale=LOCALE] [--systems=SYSTEM]
            [--manpath=PATH] [--sections=LIST] [--section=LIST] [--help]
            [--usage] [--version] KEYWORD...
```

Another excellent source is [Ubuntu Manuals a.k.a manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/), just type to search what you want.

A suggestion if you try **whatis** in terminal and press **Tab key** successfully it will show

```
Display all 9747 possibilities? (y or n)
```

You can experiment depending on above possibilities.

Also there is [**apropos**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/apropos.1.html) similar to `man -k keyword` use to search the manual page names and descriptions.

You can also use [**whereis**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/whereis.1.html) to locate the **binary, source, and manual page** files of a command as

```
whatis whereis
whereis (1)          - locate the binary, source, and manual page files for a command
```

---

**Official references**

You can refer this **Extensive** and **excellent** source at [**Ubuntu Command Line Wiki page**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CategoryCommandLine) such as [**7. Beginners/BashScripting**].

Refer [**GNU Shell Built-in Commands guide**](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands)

For **External Source** refer

[An A-Z Index of the Bash command line for Linux](http://ss64.com/bash/) explaining  **examples and Usage** .

[O'reilly Linux Command Directory](http://oreilly.com/linux/command-directory/) from [Linux in a Nutshell, 5th Edition book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596009304.do)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the help command, as this is a bash builtin, this is a lot of help while scripting

```
[11:16:07 oyrm ~]$ help
GNU bash, version 4.2.24(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
These shell commands are defined internally.  Type `help' to see this list.
Type `help name' to find out more about the function `name'.
Use `info bash' to find out more about the shell in general.
Use `man -k' or `info' to find out more about commands not in this list.
....
```

This banner is followed by a list of commands, as indicated in the banner. Try out

```
help echo
```

and I think you'll see that this is a nice, concise description of the application of the shell command