# Why is there a /bin/echo and why would I want to use it?

Tags: command-line, bash, echo

I noticed that there is a binary executable `/bin/echo` on my Ubuntu MATE 17.04 system.

I thought, that's odd, because

```
$ type echo
echo is a shell builtin
```

Cursory testing suggests that `/bin/echo` does the same sort of thing as the Bash builtin `echo`:

```
$ /bin/echo foo
foo
$ /bin/echo $USER
zanna
```

So, why is there another version of `echo` separate from the Bash program, and why or when would I want to use it?

Comment: Discussion - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1355/why-is-echo-a-shell-built-in-command

Comment: @bodhi.zazen That's quite useful even though it's not the same, because it addresses the converse of this question. That question asks why `echo` is provided as a shell builtin, while this one asks why it is provided as an external command.

Comment: One reason is that not everyone uses bash.  I would guess that /bin/echo predates bash, and the developers found it useful/efficient to include it as a built-in instead of using the executable.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

If you open up a [`bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/bash.1.html) prompt and type in an `echo` command, that uses a [shell builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins) rather than running `/bin/echo`. The reasons it is still important for `/bin/echo` to exist are:

1. You're not always using a shell. Under a variety of circumstances, you run an executable directly and not through a shell.
2. At least in theory, some shells don't have an `echo` builtin.  This is not actually required.

To expand on #1, suppose you wanted to move all the regular files whose names started with `abc` anywhere in `src` to `dest`. There are several ways to do that but one of them is:

```bash
find src -name 'abc*' -type f -exec mv -nv {} dest/ \;
```

But suppose, rather than just running that, you want to see every command that will be run first. Well, then you can prepend `echo` to the command, just as you might in other contexts:

```bash
find src -name 'abc*' -type f -exec echo mv -nv {} dest/ \;
```

But `find` doesn't use a shell. That runs `/bin/echo`.

Besides [`find`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/find.1.html) with [`-exec` or `-execdir`](http://softpanorama.biz/Tools/Find/using_exec_option_and_xargs_in_find.shtml), the `/bin/echo` executable will be called by other programs that themselves run programs but not through a shell. This [happens](https://askubuntu.com/a/625587/22949) with the [`xargs`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/xargs.1.html) command (which [is related](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/) to `find`), as well as in a number of other contexts, such as [the `Exec=` line](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#exec-variables) of [a `.desktop` file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281293/creating-a-desktop-file-for-a-new-application). Another example is when you run `sudo echo`, which can be handy for testing if `sudo` is working.

Similarly, some shells have a `printf` builtin but `/usr/bin/printf` also exists.

A less common possible reason you might deliberately use `/bin/echo` is if you were relying on the differences between it and the `echo` command provided by your shell. [`man echo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/echo.1.html) documents `/bin/echo`; [`help echo` in  `bash`](https://askubuntu.com/a/27356/22949) documents the `bash` builtin. `echo` is not very portable, because different implementations--both across operating systems and across shells on the same operating system--[support different options](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/echo+printf/) (e.g., `-e`) and [differ in their treatment of backslashes](https://askubuntu.com/a/532910/22949). Of course, it's better to avoid relying on such details, and use [`printf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/printf.1posix.html) instead, which is [far more portable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo).

In `bash`, you can make the `type` builtin show `/bin/echo` as well--assuming `/bin` is in your [`$PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)#Unix_and_Unix-like) as it always should be--by [passing it the `-a` flag](https://askubuntu.com/a/736442/22949):

```
$ type -a echo
echo is a shell builtin
echo is /bin/echo
```

Comment: And also because the [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/contents.html) says there has to be one.

Comment: @glennjackman I was hoping someone would post an answer about that, actually, and I hope you decide to do so! There's some subtlety involved, though, as neither Debian, Ubuntu, nor GNU Coreutils (nor the GNU Project overall) try to comply with POSIX in *everything*. For example, [POSIX insists a `cd` executable exist](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38819) (which, when run, changes directory and quits, leaving the caller where they were before) and some OSes have one. It may be helpful to cite [4.1 in the GNU standards](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Non_002dGNU-Standards).

Comment: @EliahKagan: Incidentaly /usr/bin/cd has a use: /usr/bin/cd directory command runs that command in that directory. If the directory change fails the command doesn't start.

Comment: @Joshua But POSIX doesn't call for that behavior, does it? [Regular builtins are to be implemented exec()ably too](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html#tag_17_06), which includes `cd`, requiring a `cd` executable, but it need only do what [the builtin](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html) does, so it needn't accept a command operand. I'm not sure what systems support `/usr/bin/cd dir cmd`, but it's unportable even across fully POSIX OSes. (And IMHO a command to simulate `(cd dir && cmd)` would be better off not named `cd`.)

Comment: @Joshua a better use of `cd` is simply as a test of ability to access a given directory: if `/usr/bin/cd some/dir` succeeds, in one shot you have tested: a) that `some/dir` exists, b) that it's a directory or a link to one, and c) the required permissions for you to access that directory exist; all without changing your own state.

Comment: `/bin` isn't in my `$PATH`, because I use a different Linux distro (Arch) that symlinks /bin to /usr/bin.

Comment: @Ferrybig No, POSIX demands the opposite: an argument to `echo` that starts with `-` is still a string operand, except the first argument--and then only if it's `-n` (though, in practice, implementations often support other options). *`mv` doesn't start with `-`.* [1003.1-2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) demands this, as did [1003.1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/echo.html) and [SUSv2](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/echo.html); none says anything like what you've stated or even contains the word "undefined."

Comment: @Ferrybig That's not to say the commands I've shown are portable, only that `-` isn't why they aren't. The one *without* `echo` is unportable as [`mv` need only support `-i` and `-f`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mv.html). The one with `echo` is unportable as the path `find` passes it may contain ``\``, giving [*implementation-defined* behavior](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html). Conforming `echo`s **are *permitted* to translate backlash escapes**, which is undesired here. Ubuntu's `/bin/echo` is GNU Coreutils echo, which doesn't.

Comment: FWIW,   `echo` and `\bin\echo` have slightly different capabilities. Back in my crazy shell-scripting days, I occasionally had one of them call the other to get exactly the information I wanted printed in exactly the format I wanted.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, see [Why is printf better than echo?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/135943)  Also it's `/bin/echo`, not `\bin\echo`, unless you're using Windows.  ;)

Answer (score 34):

Eliah's done a great job of answering this, but I want to comment about the "why is there another version of `echo` separate from the Bash program" part. That's the wrong question.

The right question is: [why is this a builtin in the first place](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1355/70524), when it could have been (and is) a perfectly fine external command?

For simplicity, take a look at the builtins in dash, a measly 38 (bash has 61, for comparison, going by the output of `compgen -b`):

```
.               continue        getopts         readonly        type
:               echo            hash            return          ulimit
[               eval            jobs            set             umask
alias           exec            kill            shift           unalias
bg              exit            local           test            unset
break           export          printf          times           wait
cd              false           pwd             trap
command         fg              read            true
```

How many of these *need* to be builtins? `[`, `echo`, `false`, `printf`, `pwd`, `test`, and `true` don't *need* to be builtins: They don't do anything that only a builtin can do (affect or obtain shell state that's not available to external commands). Bash's `printf` at least takes advantage of being a builtin: `printf -v var` saves the output to the variable `var`. `time` in bash is also special: by being a keyword, you can time arbitrary command lists in bash (dash doesn't have a `time` equivalent). `pwd` doesn't need to be a builtin either - any external command is going to inherit the current working directory (and it's an [external command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/pwd.1.html) too). `:` is an exception - you need a NOP, and `:` is it. The rest do actions that an external command can easily do.

So, a fifth of these builtins don't need to be builtins. Why, then? [The `dash` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/dash.1.html)* actually explains in passing why these are builtins (emphasis mine):

```
Builtins
 This section lists the builtin commands which are builtin because they
 need to perform some operation that can't be performed by a separate
 process.  In addition to these, there are several other commands that may
 be builtin for efficiency (e.g.  printf(1), echo(1), test(1), etc).
```

That's pretty much it: these builtins are there because they're used so often, interactively and in scripts, and their functionality is simple enough, that the shell can do the job. And so it happens: some (most?) shells took on the job.** Go back to [the `sh`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sh&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=2.9.1%20BSD&arch=default&format=html) from [2.9 BSD](http://gunkies.org/wiki/2.9BSD), and you won't find an `echo` builtin.

So, it's entirely possible a minimal shell can skip implementing such commands as builtins (I don't think any current shell does, though). The GNU coreutils project doesn't assume that you're going to run them in a particular shell, and POSIX requires these commands. So, coreutils provides these anyway, and skips those which don't have any meaning outside of the shell.

---

* This is almost identical to [the corresponding manpage text for the Almquist shell](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sh&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=NetBSD%201.0&arch=default&format=html), which is what dash, the Debian Almquist shell, is based on.

** `zsh` takes this idea to the extreme: the commands you get by loading various modules, like `zmv`, [are things you wouldn't think a shell need even get into](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html). At that point, the real question is: **why would you use bash instead of zsh, which has all these builtins?**

Comment: It turns out that : doesn't need to be a builtin either. It's just silly for it to not be a builtin. Unless you're dealing with early init rescue-floppy-disk level problems (in which case I discovered the hard way pwd doesn't work reliably either) the only penalty for not having this as a builtin is terrible performance.

Comment: @Joshua no, `:` as an external wouldn't really be a NOP, you'd still have `PATH` lookup, an attempt to execute the command, etc., when all you really want is to expressly do nothing. `:` as a builtin does that.

Comment: Bash actually does need `pwd` to be built-in for it to work the way it does, with the default behaviour of showing the "logical" path (`pwd -L`).  `/bin/pwd` could only implement the `pwd -P` behaviour of showing you the actual parent directories, not the symlink you `cd`ed through.

Comment: @PeterCordes `pwd`'s status is a bit compromised by the presence of `PWD`, but yes, that's also an instance of bash using the builtin status to improve functionality