# I accidentally unset $PATH. Why did `echo` still work?

Tags: command-line, bash

So there I was. Trying to append to `$PATH`. Uh oh! I accidentally unset `$PATH`! For whatever reason I ran

```
$ ls
bash: ls: command not found
```

To be expected. Then I ran

```
$ echo $PATH
$PATH:/home/jon/.local/bin
```

Is `echo` some sort of special case? Why isn't it on `$PATH`? Is it built in to bash?

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! _“I accidentally unset `$PATH`!”_ Not really, you seem to have set it to a not wanted value. Since your PATH now contains `$PATH` literally, you must have used single quotes (`'`) instead of double quotes (`"`): `export PATH='$PATH:/home/jon/.local/bin'`, haven’t you?

Comment: Related: [Why is there a /bin/echo and why would I want to use it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960822)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`echo` is a bash builtin. It does not use the `$PATH` to find the `echo` program, instead bash has it's own version of `echo` which is used instead of the `echo` program located in your `$PATH`

read more here:
[Bash Builtins (Bash Reference Manual)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html)

Comment: There's also `/bin/echo`, which would have vanished when OP unset `$PATH`

Comment: @waltinator except, if you call it as `/bin/echo` it would still work regardless of `PATH`, and if you call it as `echo`, you get the builtin and not `/bin/echo` :)

Answer (score 25):

In addition to what Minijack mentioned, you can check what a command is by using the `type` builtin.

```
$ type echo
echo is a shell builtin
```

On the other hand, `which` can be used to check for executables specifically. Once you unset $PATH, you'll get something like

```
$ which echo
/usr/bin/which: no echo in ((null))
```

Whereas with your path set you get

```
/usr/bin/echo
```

You can check `man builtins` for list and desription of various builtins. For example, `[` and `test` are also builtins.

EDIT: `which` works for me even without PATH because of an alias that uses an absolute path

Comment: Without `PATH`, even `which` wouldn't be found, right?

Comment: @AngewisnolongerproudofSO and without `PATH`, also `man builtins` wouldn't work :-)

Comment: @AngewisnolongerproudofSO for me which works without path as it's apparently aliased to `alias|/usr/bin/which --tty-only --read-alias --show-dot --show-tilde` i.e. an absolute path. man is not, so @andreee is indeed correct that doesn't work

Comment: There's no reason to ever use `which`. If you want to know about executables, use [`type`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-type) with `-a`, `-P`, or `-p`.

Comment: @wjandrea what's wrong with which?

Comment: @vikarjramun It's not a builtin, so in this case where OP's PATH is messed up, it's inaccessible (or at least it can't be looked up), but `type` will still work with what's left of the PATH, i.e. `/home/jon/.local/bin`. As well, `type` is more informative in general, e.g. it knows about hashed paths but `which` doesn't.

Comment: By default `type` simply returns the first hit. If you want to see all of them, use `type -a echo` which will include the one found at `/usr/bin`. The difference between `type` and `which` is that `which` _only_ looks at directories in your `$PATH`, while `type` will look everywhere, including shell builtins, functions etc. As a general rule, [`type` is always preferred over `which`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then/85250?r=SearchResults&s=9|0.0000#85250), for this reason among others.

Answer (score 3):

The model employed by the *Single Unix Specification* (a.k.a. IEEE 1003.1) is that whether a command is built into a shell is a mere optimization, and the behaviour (if invoked in a conformant manner) should be the same for a built-in version of a command as for an external version.  (This is *regular* built-ins, that is.  Special built-ins are another matter.)  In particular, if the command is not found as an external in a `PATH` search, the built-in version is not to be executed.

This is indeed what happens with one shell.  You'll find that the Watanabe shell conforms to the *SUS*.  In its `posixly-correct` mode, if `echo` is not on the path, the built-in `echo` command in the Watanabe shell will not be executed.

But the 93 Korn, Debian Almquist, Z, and Bourne Again shells in their most conformant modes still all execute built-ins *even if* there is no corresponding executable on `PATH`.  That is what is happening here for you.  The Bourne Again shell has a built-in `echo` command, and several others besides.  It is executing that, even though it has not found an external `echo` command in a `PATH` search.

(Note that there are quite a few ways to invoke `echo` in a non-conformant manner, or at least in a manner where the result is unspecified: Using `-n`; using a backslash in any argument; using `-e`; using other things expecting them to be command options or end of options markers.  These not only reveal whether it is a built-in `echo`, but even to an extent reveal what shell is in use.  Fortunately, you did not hit any of them.  ☺)

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/496377/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/496291/5132
- "[Command search and execution](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01_01)".  *Shell Command Language*.  IEEE Std 1003.1-2017. The Open Group.
- [`echo`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html#tag_20_37).  *Utilities*.  IEEE Std 1003.1-2017. The Open Group.
- "[Why is `printf` better than `echo`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/5132)"

Comment: I suspect the reason a lot of shells stil invoke a builtin even if the exacutable is present is the same they have it as a builtin to begin with, speed. Searching for the exacutable wastes time, and they have those builtins specifically to save time.